# Replace an element with Dom Document PHP

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I load a html page with PHP Dom Document :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

I search in my page all `"a"` elements, and if they realize my condition i need to replace for example `<a href="blablablabla">My link is beautiful</a>` by just `My link is beautiful`

Here my loop :

```
$liens = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($liens as $lien){
    if($lien->hasAttribute('href')){
        if (preg_match("/metz2/i", $lien->getAttribute('href'))) {
        //HERE I NEED TO REPLACE </a>           
        }
        $cpt++;
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas ? Suggestions ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time i need to manage DOM with PHP, i use a framework called **PHP Simple HTLM DOM** parser. ([Link here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/))

It's very easy to use, something like this might work for you:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.page.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    //Do your custom logic here if you need it, for example this extracts the inner contents of the a-tag, and puts it freely.
    $inner = $element->innertext;
    $element->outertext($inner);
}

//To echo modified html again:
echo $html;
```

Answer (score -2):

Could be done with [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) as well:

```
$sText = '<a href="asdasdasd">Stackoverflow</a>';

$sText = preg_replace( '/<a.*>(.*)<\/a>/',  '$1', $sText );

echo $sText;
```